# Assign a different string to a number - JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is it possible to assign an entirely different string to a number in JSON?
It is stored online so I can't change it.

```
{
id: 1,
photo: "48844.jpg",
web_name: "Ospina",
team_code: 3,
status: "a",
code: 48844,
first_name: "David",
second_name: "Ospina",
squad_number: 13,
minutes: 143,
goals_scored: 0,
assists: 0,
clean_sheets: 0,
goals_conceded: 4,
own_goals: 0,
penalties_saved: 0,
penalties_missed: 0,
yellow_cards: 0,
red_cards: 0,
saves: 4,
element_type: 1,
team: 1
}
```

json

```
function goalkeeperstat(element){
$('#result1').empty();
$('.amount').empty();

var category = element.getAttribute("value");
var categoryprompt = element.getAttribute("name");
var position = 1;
var fr = $(json).filter(function (i,n){return n.element_type===position & n[category] >= slidervalueg1.val() && n[category] <= slidervalueg2.val() });

for (var i=0;i<fr.length;i++)
{
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML += ("<div class='profile'><img src='https://platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/110x140/p" + fr[i].code + ".png'/><div class='playerinfo'><p>Name: " + fr[i].first_name + " " + fr[i].second_name + "</p><p>Position: Goalkeeper</p><p class='teamname'>Team: " + fr[i].team + "</p></div><div class='infobg'><p>" + categoryprompt + ": <span class='categoryprompt'>" + fr[i][category] + "</span></p><p>Minutes: " + fr[i].minutes + "</p><p>Minutes per " + categoryprompt + ": " + parseFloat(Math.round((fr[i].minutes / fr[i][category]) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + "</p></div></div>");

}
}
```

script.js

In the for loop I have fr[i].team which is obviously displaying 1 for the player I've posted but I would like to display "Arsenal".

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning displaying a different label for different items? If so, then return that value on your json.

Comment: You can make a dictionary, which will have the teams names against their id's. In for loop you can map them and display their name instead of the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionaries in javascript:

```
var dictionary = {};
dictionary['1'] = "arsenal"
```

in your code you can use:

```
alert(dictionary['1']); // arsenal
```

Comment: If I then have for example

var dictionary = {};
dictionary['1'] = "arsenal",
dictionary['2'] = "bournemouth"

How would I display it in the code so that the right player has the right team assigned to them?

Because the JSON has hundreds of players assigned to 20 different teams

Comment: replace `fr[i].team` with `dictionary[fr[i].team.toString()]`, supposing that you have already defined your dictionary with all possible teams.